# Will Ruta support all type of spaces?-Uima Ruta

Tags: uima, ruta

I need to know whether ruta support all type of spaces.I've tried to annotate **Fig 1.1 and Fig 1.2**.

**Sample Code:**

```
 PACKAGE uima.ruta.example;
 DECLARE FigNo;
 (W{REGEXP("Fig",true)} NUM PERIOD NUM){->MARK(FigNo)};
```

**Input:**

```
 Fig 1.1
 Fig 1.2
```

**Expected Output:**

```
 Fig 1.1
 Fig 1.2
```

But for me only Fig 1.1 is coming under FigNo. The difference between Fig 1.1 and Fig 1.2 is Space (Fig **thinspace** 1.1 and Fig **emspace** 1.2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How to answer this question?

Yes, UIMA Ruta will support all types of spaces, if someone opens a ticket for it [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/issues/?jql=project%20%3D%20UIMA%20AND%20component%20%3D%20ruta) and someone implements the changes, e.g., by uploading a patch.

If you are the first someone, I'll do the part of the second someone.

*DISCLAIMER: I am a developer of UIMA Ruta*